# what is the word origin of myelo- as in myelofibrosis or myeloma?

Tags: cancer, terminology, hematology

what is the word origin of myelo- as in myelofibrosis or myeloma? I know that these are plasma cancers originating in the bone marrow.

Comment: It's greek, and brings with it the meaning: "marrow", "spinal cord", or "brain". [source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=myelo-&allowed_in_frame=)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the etymology of words and not biology.

Answer (score 3):

[myelo-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myelo-) is from Greek related to the word for 'marrow'.

See also: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/myelo-

Most cancers are named in a similar matter, with the tissue of origin followed by the suffix "-oma": glioma from glial cells, sarcoma from the connective tissues/"flesh",

Answer (score 0):

medical terms are mainly based on Greek and Latin words, myel(myelo) is a root which means bone marrow and it also can mean spinal cord , it depends on the word. in myeloma , myelo means bone marrow and oma is a suffix which means tumor just like lymphom( cancer of lymphatic system ).
ex: meylitis: inflammation of spinal cord , but , myeloma : cancer of the bone marrow

Comment: Read the comments of a respected user — comments that have been upvoted — and follow the injunction in the Help section on answering questions: [Answer well-asked questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).